# Remove the custom view from uiviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Lets say I have an `AViewcontrollers` and `BviewControllers`. I added a BViewcontrollers view as an subview to the `Aviewcontrollers` view. I want to remove `BviewController` view from the `AViewController` view.

I am trying in this way for removing the 'b view' but it is not success.

```
AViewcontrollers *aVC = [[AviewControllers alloc] initWithNibName:@"AViewcontrollers" bundle:nil];
BViewcontrollers *bVC = [[BviewControllers alloc] initWithNibName:@"BViewcontrollers" bundle:nil];;

[aVC addsubView:bVc.view];

  //Trying to remove the 'b view' from the 'a view' 
for (UIView *subview in [[aVC view] subviews] ) {
        NSLog(@"Subview::%@",[subview class]);
       if ([subview isMemberOfClass:[BViewControllers class]]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
            NSLog(@"This subview Belongs to tools view controller");
        }  }
```

Answer (score 4):

The obvious answer is:

```
[bVC.view removeFromSuperview];
```

The problem with your code above is that you're checking if the view is a `BviewControllers` class, not a view of `BviewControllers`. If the view had a specific class (say `Bview`), then you could do that check (`if ([subview isMemberOfClass:[BView class]])`).

Using `isMemberOfClass:` is also very specific so you're usually better off using `isKindOfClass:`

Comment: how can we verify the BView?we didn't have an instance of it we are adding in one view and removing in another view

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that question. You need some way to identify the view, preferably a reference to it or a known tag value. Trying to compare the class is the least reliable / maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully your bViewController has a reference to the view? if so you can call:

```
[bVC.view removeFromSuperview]
```

Comment: I'll note that this design pattern seems a little fragile. You may want to consider moving this view to be fully controlled by AviewController.

Comment: we adding in one controller and removing when app enters into background.we didn't have an reference of the bvc.view

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding the BViewController as a child of AViewController, in addition to adding B's view as a subview of A. Doing this will allow forwarding of autorotation events, among other things; Something like:

```
AViewController *aVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
BViewController *bVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

[aVC addChildViewController:bVC];
[bVC didMoveToParentViewController:aVC];

[aVC.view addSubview:bVC.view];
```

Then, when you want to remove the the view (and controller), you can iterate through the child view controllers. (or store a pointer in some other way)

```
for (UIViewController *vc in aVC.childViewControllers){
    if ([vc isKindOfClass:[BViewController class]]){
        [vc.view removeFromSuperview];
        [vc removeFromParentViewController];
        [vc didMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: we are developing an app for ipad and iphone . in ipad we are giving it to the popovercontroller and by using the notification we dismissing . in iphone case we are adding it as an subview.In my project we are adding at one view controller and removing when app goes to background

Comment: I would still do it this way for the iPhone, it is good practice to keep the viewcontroller hierarchy in sync with the view hierarchy. for the iPad popover, you are already passing the viewcontroller into the popover, so it handles the rest automagically.